# Scrolling on Google Home Nest device stops the speaking response

Tags: actions-on-google, google-home

When a longer response appears on a Nest Google Home device (i.e., one that spans more than a single frame), and a user scrolls through the message:

1. The action stops speaking at the moment the scrolling begins, rather than continue reading the rest of the response.
2. If a question has been asked, it doesn’t respond when replying directly the training phrase.  Instead, the user has to say “Hey Google, $training phrase”. And thus it appears that the session has actually ended when it hasn't.

I verified that Google really does not quit the conversation as imagined above after scrolling. Instead, it only stops listening.

**Questions**

1. Is there a way to keep the Assistant (Google home device) listening to the returned response even though the user started to scroll to see the remaining text?
2. Is the point two described above a standard behavior of the Smart home devices? If not, how can I make the Assistant listen to a user reply without having to say "Hey Google"?

Comment: Have you tested your action [through the simulator](https://developers.google.com/assistant/console/simulator#specify_a_device) to see if this behavior occurs across devices?